# Как на JavaScript отразить вертикально base64 jpeg?

Tags: javascript, base64

Изображение приходит с сервера и записывается в буфер, после чего вставляется в `<img src="...">`. В некоторых случаях изображение перевёрнуто и его надо отражать вертикально **до вставки в `<img src="...">`**.

**Есть ли какие-то стандартные средства перевернуть `data:image/jpeg;base64,...` в буфере?**

*PS: есть алгоритм на C++ для отражения RGB, но не хотелось бы декодировать base64, отсекать JFIF-заголовок, потом опять кодировать... Это всё дополнительное время выполнения операции, которое в дефиците, тем более JS не C++ и работает не так быстро.*

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: а чем не подходит переворачивать/отражать эти изображения через CSS?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, вот я туплю... Спасибо!